# Strange bug with the StackOverflow Inbox Panel links on IE11 in Windows 7

Tags: bug, status-norepro, global-inbox, windows-7, internet-explorer-11

As the title says, there seems to be a strange bug in the StackOverflow Inbox Panel links on IE11. It could occur on other browsers too, but I tried Chrome and it didn't occur using that. It *is* repeatable on IE11, although I'm not sure whether it's a StackOverflow bug or an IE11 bug.

So anyway, I noticed that when I click on a link to a post in the Inbox, it takes me to the relevant page and then nicely scrolls the page to the relevant comment. This is good until I want to scroll the page. After clicking on any link in the Inbox, I can't then scroll on the loaded page. It's not just mouse scrolling that doesn't work either... the keyboard arrow keys no longer work either. Only the <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd> keys and manually moving the scroll bar still function properly.

After looking into it a little, I noticed some other things too. If I had earned some reputation for a particular question, I could click on the link to it from the Achievements Panel *and still scroll the loaded page*. Also, when clicking on a normal link to the same post from a search result, scrolling was not affected. So I took note of the three different links to the same post and then noticed something:

The first link is the normal search result link: [Binding an Image in WPF MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788855/binding-an-image-in-wpf-mvvm)
It has the format `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/id/name`

The second link is the link to the answer: [Binding an Image in WPF MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788855/binding-an-image-in-wpf-mvvm/21789092#21789092)
It has the format `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/id/name/21789092#21789092`

The third link is the link to the comment with the bug: [Binding an Image in WPF MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788855/binding-an-image-in-wpf-mvvm/21789092?noredirect=1#comment32970507_21789092)
It has the format `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/id/name/21789092?noredirect=1#comment32970507_21789092`

If you have IE11, then you'll be able to scroll the pages navigated to by the first two links, but not the last one, even though all three of them are *actually* the *same* page. By looking at the different URLs, it seems as though there could be some problem with the `noredirect=1` part. I've seen this faulty functionality from my work computer too, but I'd be interested to hear if anyone else can also confirm this.

---

UPADTE >>>

Hey guys, I've noticed that this bug *also* occurs in IE11 on Windows 8, but just in a different place. Instead of using the Inbox links, just edit (not add) a comment... when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you see a flashing text entry cursor to the right of the 'edit' link and the page can *not* be scrolled, unless manually using the scroll bar. In fact, even the <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd> keys no longer work.

I found that if you click in one of the comments, the normal scrolling functionality returns. I also noticed that after editing a comment, the page gets that `noredirect` query string parameter again:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/id/name/21791103?noredirect=1#comment33042046_21791103
```

Please note that this also occurs on Windows 7.

Comment: Using IE11 on Windows 8.1 - cannot reproduce. Do you have any plugins/add-ins installed? Are you seeing any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: Nope, no plug ins installed. I've just had my computer at work upgraded to Windows 8 and I can no longer reproduce this problem. I *can* still reproduce it on Windows 7, so please remove that `status-norepro` tag. I will edit my question to clearly state that this only happens on Windows 7.

Comment: No-repro on Windows 7, IE11.

Comment: Really? That's strange. I'll have another check when I get home.

Comment: No repro, clean IE 11 on Windows 7. Press F12 and then CTRL+2 to activate the JavaScript console then try again. Do you see any errors?

Comment: *I'll have another check when I get home.*

Comment: Tried again, IE 11 Windows 7. No repro.

Comment: Yep fine, I've now re-tested at home on Windows 7 and the problem seems to have been fixed now. Thanks for trying. However, the bug mentioned in my UPDATE *is* still reproducible. Edit a comment once, or maybe twice and then the page will freeze and you won't be able to scroll. And that is on *both* Windows 7 *and* 8. Maybe I should add that as a separate bug?

Comment: Strange, but I *do* have that problem again... I can't scroll the page after clicking on the Inbox link. Windows 7 and IE11.

Comment: Is no one listening now that there is a 'StatusNoRepro' tag on this question? This problem *definitely* still exists. I've had it on Windows 7 and while it doesn't have quite the same effect on Windows 8, it *does* actually occur... it just affects the scrolling, making it 'stutter'. And all these negative effects can be fixed when I simply remove the query string from the URL. Can someone else please check this for me?